# prevent the auto-population of all groups scope when creating/working with users

Tags: 2013

Is there any configuration one can to do prevent the auto-population of group scope when creating users in SDL Tridion 2013?

When selecting a group for a user in the CMS GUI, default will be all publications set as scope. And it is irritating to manually undo all. It takes time when you have a large volume of publications. We got some tools that creates users for us but sometime, you need to work in the CMS GUI and you just waste so much time.

But can there be a way to "work" around that crappy option they did develop into the CMS?

Put the Q in "plain" stackexchange so do know the Mark All and "Spacebar" trick. But would be faster if you could avoid this feature somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use Groups & Sub-Groups and to control the Scope through this relationship, rather than having to set it for every user.

For example... You create a group called `Mysite Chief Editor` that is a member of the default `Chief Editor` Group, but you set the Scope here, so that the `Mysite Chief Editor` is only a member of the `Chief Editor` Group in the Publications that you desire.

Then, when you add a new User, you can set them as a member of the new `Mysite Chief Editor` Group and leave their Scope as `All Publications`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way in the UI itself. If you're willing to do your user/group updates via the core service, then you can do it easily. but, that doesn't really help you improve the CME UI...